# Cómo cargar el plugin class 'com.avenstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter'?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Realicé un Proyecto para hacer pruebas automatizadas con Java, Selenium y Cucumber, y al momento de configurar el código para la emisión de reportes, me arroja el siguiente error:

%ERROR  2,initializationError(runner.Runner)
%TRACES
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The plugin specification 'com.avenstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:' has a problem:

Could not load plugin class 'com.avenstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter'.

Plugin specifications should have the format of PLUGIN[:[PATH|[URI [OPTIONS]]]

Valid values for PLUGIN are: html, json, junit, message, pretty, progress, rerun, summary, teamcity, testng, timeline, unused, usage

PLUGIN can also be a fully qualified class name, allowing registration of 3rd party plugins. The 3rd party plugin must implement io.cucumber.plugin.Plugin
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.createCouldNotLoadClass(PluginOption.java:167)
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parsePluginName(PluginOption.java:145)
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parse(PluginOption.java:104)
at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:68)
at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.addPlugins(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:85)
at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.parse(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:39)
at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:120)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.avenstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.parsePluginName(PluginOption.java:139)
... 23 more

El código del archivo build.gradle es:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.15.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java
    implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '7.14.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cucumber-junit
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.14.0'

    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.32'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.avenstack/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter 
    implementation group: 'com.aventstack', name: 'extentreports-cucumber4-adapter', version: '1.0.7'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'seleniumproj.App'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

// Ejecutar tags desde la línea de comando con la tarea Test
test {
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
}
```

El codigo del Runner.java es:

```
package runner;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import pages.BasePage;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features", glue = "steps", plugin = {
        "com.avenstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
        "json:target/cucumber-reports.json" }, monochrome = true)

public class Runner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanDriver() {
        BasePage.closeBrowser();
    }
}
```

Cree la carpeta target para recibir el .json cucumber-reports.json y la carpeta test-output que contiene una carpeta llamada HtmlReport y esta a su vez el archivo ExtendHtml.html. Hice gradle clean, gradle build y gradle test todos ejecutados con éxito. Estoy trabajando con openjdk version "17.0.9", Gradle 8.4 y io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.14.0

Por favor pueden darme una mano para resolver la carga del plugin y generar el reporte respectivo?

Muchas Gracias a Todos!

Answer (score 0):

Ya q utilizas el cucumber 7, lo correcto es usar el adaptador de la misma version, en este sitio: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber7-adapter/1.14.0.
De otro lado el "plugin" del runner.java, tambien tiene un cambio para esa version:

```
plugin = {"pretty",
  "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
  "timeline:test-output-thread/" },
```